# Is there any way to run a test using the AZURE test plans, if the test runner is playwright

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, playwright, playwright-test

Use Azure Test plans to run Playwright tests.
[image]

- have used playwright to write the tests.
- have used https://github.com/alexneo2003/playwright-azure-reporter to link my Playwright tests on the Azure Test plans UI.

Using the test-id in the testcase and test-plan id the status of the test-case updates automatically when I run it on local.

- Issue is the Release is giving me errors
  [image]
- These are the agents used
  [image]

These are the final release logs showing the error.

```
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2426224Z ##[section]Starting: Test run for Test plans
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2559828Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2559968Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2560043Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2560348Z Version      : 2.220.0
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2560401Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2560462Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest
2023-06-02T14:57:59.2560567Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3058583Z In distributed testing flow
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3077496Z ======================================================
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3079111Z Test selector : Test run
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3079824Z Test run Id : '1252'
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3080453Z Search folder : D:\a\r1\a
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3236970Z Action when minimum tests threshold not met : donothing
2023-06-02T14:58:00.3237423Z Minimum tests expected to be run: 0
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4935759Z Distributed test execution, number of agents in job : 1
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4940255Z Run in parallel : true
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4940822Z Run in isolation : false
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4941390Z Path to custom adapters : undefined
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4942908Z Other console options : undefined
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4943474Z Code coverage enabled : true
2023-06-02T14:58:00.4944370Z Diagnostics enabled : false
2023-06-02T14:58:00.5055695Z ======================================================
2023-06-02T14:58:00.5057191Z Source filter: **\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**
2023-06-02T14:58:00.8086198Z ##[warning]Test Impact (Run only Impacted tests) and Code Coverage data collector will not work.
2023-06-02T14:58:00.8169345Z ##[warning]Test Impact (Run only Impacted tests) and Code Coverage data collector will not work.
2023-06-02T14:58:00.9425920Z ##[warning]Test Impact (Run only Impacted tests) and Code Coverage data collector will not work.
2023-06-02T14:58:00.9432577Z [command]D:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.220.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe --inputFile D:\a\_temp\input_de58bef0-0155-11ee-b343-0d93038107f1.json
2023-06-02T14:58:01.0151854Z ##########################################################################
2023-06-02T14:58:01.0152528Z DtaExecutionHost version 19.210.32906.4.
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3832334Z ===========================================
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3832918Z AgentName: fv-az474-61-Hosted Agent-8
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3833330Z ServiceUrl: https://dev.azure.com/ThoucentricLabs/
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3833644Z TestPlatformVersion: 17.6.1
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3833993Z EnvironmentUri: vstest://env/Thousense Lite/_apis/release/28/2676/3056/1
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3834303Z QueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 3000
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3834594Z MaxQueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 10000
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3834905Z QueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 3000
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3835201Z MaxQueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 50000
2023-06-02T14:58:02.3835508Z ===========================================
2023-06-02T14:58:02.7471413Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2023-06-02T14:58:02.7586215Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2023-06-02T14:58:02.8726967Z TestExecutionHost.Execute: Registered TestAgent : 17 : fv-az474-61-Hosted Agent-8
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9065696Z IsValidServiceResponse: Received None command..Service Workflow is not active
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9220949Z Updated Run Settings:
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9235831Z <RunSettings>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9236212Z   <RunConfiguration>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9236604Z     <MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9239252Z     <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9239615Z     <ResultsDirectory>D:\a\_temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9239943Z   </RunConfiguration>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9240204Z   <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9240477Z     <DataCollectors>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9240949Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9241445Z         <Configuration>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9241694Z           <CodeCoverage>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9241940Z             <ModulePaths>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9242221Z               <Include>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9242481Z                 <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9242774Z                 <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9243038Z               </Include>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9243274Z               <Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9243568Z                 <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9244060Z               </Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9244324Z             </ModulePaths>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9244566Z             <Functions>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9244822Z               <Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9245096Z                 <Function>^Fabrikam\.UnitTest\..*</Function>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9245414Z                 <Function>^std::.*</Function>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9245730Z                 <Function>^ATL::.*</Function>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9249889Z                 <Function>.*::__GetTestMethodInfo.*</Function>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9250731Z                 <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppCodeCoverageFramework::.*</Function>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9251293Z                 <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::.*</Function>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9251769Z               </Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9252186Z             </Functions>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9252569Z             <Attributes>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9252973Z               <Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9253441Z                 <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9253960Z                 <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9254490Z                 <Attribute>^System\.Runtime\.CompilerServices\.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9255002Z                 <Attribute>^System\.CodeDom\.Compiler\.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9255484Z                 <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.CodeAnalysis\.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9255954Z               </Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9256331Z             </Attributes>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9256704Z             <Sources>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9257107Z               <Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9257491Z                 <Source>.*\\atlmfc\\.*</Source>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9257909Z                 <Source>.*\\vctools\\.*</Source>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9258309Z                 <Source>.*\\public\\sdk\\.*</Source>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9258712Z                 <Source>.*\\microsoft sdks\\.*</Source>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9259139Z                 <Source>.*\\vc\\include\\.*</Source>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9259520Z               </Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9259914Z             </Sources>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9260287Z             <CompanyNames>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9260659Z               <Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9261074Z                 <CompanyName>.*microsoft.*</CompanyName>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9261460Z               </Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9262148Z             </CompanyNames>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9262541Z             <PublicKeyTokens>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9262908Z               <Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9263338Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^B77A5C561934E089$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9264484Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^B03F5F7F11D50A3A$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9264961Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^31BF3856AD364E35$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9265398Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^89845DCD8080CC91$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9265834Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^71E9BCE111E9429C$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9266293Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^8F50407C4E9E73B6$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9266727Z                 <PublicKeyToken>^E361AF139669C375$</PublicKeyToken>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9267147Z               </Exclude>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9267519Z             </PublicKeyTokens>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9268021Z             <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9268499Z             <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9268977Z             <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9269443Z             <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9269866Z           </CodeCoverage>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9270245Z         </Configuration>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9270644Z       </DataCollector>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9271022Z     </DataCollectors>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9271406Z   </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2023-06-02T14:58:02.9271817Z </RunSettings>
2023-06-02T14:58:03.0153299Z Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters
2023-06-02T14:58:03.0154050Z SourceFilter: *.dll TestCaseFilter: 
2023-06-02T14:58:03.0155281Z Run title: TestRun_Frontend-Playwright-Testing - CD_Release-12
2023-06-02T14:58:03.0155607Z Build location: D:\a\r1\a
2023-06-02T14:58:03.0155865Z Build Id: 13644
2023-06-02T14:58:03.3116801Z Test run with Id 1252 associated
2023-06-02T14:58:13.9551089Z Received the command : Start
2023-06-02T14:58:13.9566195Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Start Command handled
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0196996Z Received the command : Stop
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0197536Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Stop Command handled
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0207678Z SliceFetch Aborted. Moving to the TestHostEnd phase
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0744002Z Please use this link to analyze the test run : https://dev.azure.com/ThoucentricLabs/Thousense Lite/_TestManagement/Runs#_a=resultQuery&runId=1252&queryPath=Recent+Run%2FRun1252
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0744760Z Test run '1252' is in 'Aborted' state with 'Total Tests' : 1 and 'Passed Tests' : 0.
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0794651Z ##[error]Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2023-06-02T14:58:35.0817561Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
2023-06-02T14:58:35.1344802Z ##########################################################################
2023-06-02T14:58:35.1672782Z ##[section]Finishing: Test run for Test plans
```

This is my playwright.config.ts file

Ignore the `provided`

```
export default defineConfig({
    testDir: "./tests",
    fullyParallel: true,
    forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
    workers: process.env.CI ? 4 : 4,
    reporter: [
        ["html", { open: "never" }],
        ["list"],
        ["junit", { outputFile: "results.xml" }],
        [
            "@alex_neo/playwright-azure-reporter",
            {
                orgUrl: "<provided>",
                token: "<provided>",
                planId: 3691,
                projectName: "<provided>",
                environment: "dev",
                logging: true,
                testRunTitle: "Playwright Test Run",
                publishTestResultsMode: "testRun",
                uploadAttachments: true,
                attachmentsType: ["screenshot", "video", "trace"],
                testRunConfig: {
                    owner: {
                        displayName: "Ritav Das",
                    },
                    comment: "Playwright Test Run",
                    configurationIds: [10],
                },
            } as AzureReporterOptions,
        ],
    ],
    use: {
        trace: "on-first-retry",
        screenshot: "only-on-failure",
        actionTimeout: 0,
    },
    projects: [
        {
            name: "chromium",
            use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
        },
    ],
});
```

This is my azure-pipelines-pw.yml file

```
trigger:
  - feature/playwright

pool: Default

steps:
  - script: echo "Testing code with Playwright"
    displayName: "Playwright"

  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "16.x"
    displayName: "Use Node.js"

  - script: |
      npm install @playwright/test axios jwt-decode ----legacy-peer-deps
      echo "$(BUILD_VM_PASSWORD)" | sudo -S npx playwright install --with-deps
      npx playwright install
      npx playwright test --reporter=html --workers=4 || exit 0 
      PLAYWRIGHT_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME=results.xml npx playwright test --workers=4 --reporter=junit || exit 0
    displayName: "Install dependencies & Run tests"
    env:
      CI: true

  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/playwright-report
    artifact: playwright-report
    # always create the artifact, this is useful for debugging failed tests
    condition: always()

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: "JUnit"
      testResultsFiles: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/results.xml
      mergeTestResults: true
      failTaskOnFailedTests: true
    condition: always()
```

My build pipeline completes successfully.
[image]

Shows all the 15 tests everything perfect. The problem comes when it's time for the release

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following screenshot for the Release pipeline tasks which have to be configured to make it work.

[image: screenshot]

The VS Test tasks are not compatible with Playwright. The way you created the build pipeline using yml is perfect and you just need to replicate it using the Tasks from Release pipeline UI since it doesn't support the yml file as the input.

Comment: User is looking for YAML pipeline not classic release information. I am not sure if this provides enough detail to answer the question